# How can I verify if my application has access to the Here geocoder api?

Tags: here-api

I'm implementing Here API geocoder, and my application works almost always behind firewalls. How can I know if the application has access to geocoder api without using credentials? Is there same url that I can call to check if I have access to it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. For everyone else to understand and be able to help you, please consider editing your question. You could start by reading this article: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try reformulating the question. It will help others reproduce the problem and maybe find an answer.

Comment: In order to access HERE geocoder API,  passing app_code and app_id in API call is must, which cannot be bypassed

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall allows HTTPS traffic from your application, then you should have access to HERE APIs.

In practice, you can try to send the following GET request:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?city=Chicago&app_id=123&app_code=123
```

Since `app_id` and `app_code` are filled with the dummy *123* value, the expected behaviour, in case the request is not blocked by the firewall, would be to receive an HTTP response code of `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Comment: @SergioRPires Please consider vote/marking the question answered, so that it helps other finding questions which are really unanswered.